# How to make a button on Xcode

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm new at Xcode and swift UI

I need help how to create a button
Why is it more complicated than Android?

I have view that call Profileview and I want to Navigation to NewOrderview, I know I need to use the NavigationLink.

As you can see at my code I have 2 button as a Section and I like that button that have title "New Order" to Navigation to new View call NewOrderView.

I can see the arrow but it not Nav to NewOrderView

I will be glad for any help

This is my code ProfileView

```
                    Section("Windows"){
                   
                        NavigationStack{
                            NavigationView{
                                NavigationLink(destination: NewOrderView()) {
                                    
                                label: do {
                                    SettingRowView(imageName: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.forward.fill",
                                                   title: "New Order",
                                                   tinColor: .gray)
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Button{
                            print("Show Database..")
                        } label: {
                            SettingRowView(imageName: "externaldrive.connected.to.line.below.fill",
                                           title: "Show Database",
                                           tinColor: .gray)
                        }
                    
                }
```

[This is the emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYJXh.png)

Comment: You should look at the Apple SwiftUI Tutorials, Do you have more than 1 navigation stack in your app? Also put the Button inside the VStack not at the same level because that essentially makes another pane. Because they are both at the same level in the Stack

Comment: I edit my post maybe now it more clear , As you can see on the screen shot I made I like the New order will Nav to a new view call NewOrderView

Comment: Get rid of all the NavigationView, you only need 1 NavigationStack at the top of your app. This is your issue.

Comment: I remove the NavigationVIew and it still not open the NewOrderView

Comment: I do that and it work thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NavigationStack` in conjunction with `NavigationLink(value:,label:)` and `navigationDestination`, which is the "newer" way of handling navigation in SwiftUI.

```
NavigationStack {
    Section("Windows") {
        NavigationLink(value: "this-string-defines-the-destination") {
            SettingRowView(...)
        }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { navigationValue in
        SettingDetailView(for: navigationValue)
    }

    Section {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a bit more complicated than the "old" `NavigationLink(destination: () -> View, label: () -> View)`, but also more flexible.

This allows you to "push a value onto the navigation stack". In my example a `String` of value "this-string-defines-the-destination". SwiftUI will then look whether it can find a handler for navigation with `String` values and will find the `.navigationDestination(for: String.self)`.

You can also push other types onto the stack (you can also mix types, e.g. push Strings, Ints or any custom type), as long as they conform to `Hashable`.

This documentation page by Apple goes a bit more into detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack

Small note: it's best to decide on *one* approach for your entire app.
Either go with the old `NavigationLink(destination: () -> View, label: () -> View)`
or go with the new `NavigationLink(value: Hashable, label: () -> View)`.
Mixing both approaches will cause issues.

Edit: some details on your updates to your question

1. Use *either* the `NavigationStack` *or* the `NavigationView`, but nesting both into each other won't work and will cause issues.
2. The `NavigationStack` only needs to be defined once on the *top level* in the app. Any other view you display within that stack or any view that navigate to in that stack, must *not* to redefine a new NavigationStack. (Navigation will break if you do)

So in short: Define one outer `NavigationStack` at the top level.

Comment: I try that but it not pass me to a NewOrderView

Comment: @TamirYosef your code example does not show that, so it's hard to help. One issue might be that you don't define the `.navigationDestination` *inside* of the `NavigationStack`. Or you don't define the destination for the type that you're passing in as a `value` in the NavigationLink. As I said, it's hard to help without seeing the code that you're working with.

Comment: I edit my post maybe now it more clear , As you can see on the screen shot I made I like the New order will Nav to a new view call NewOrderView

Comment: I edited my answer in turn. In short: Define one outer NavigationStack at the top level. Don't nest NavigationStacks and NavigationViews.

Comment: Can you fix my code that I can see how to do it ?